# c++ statx() syscall do not work in Cloud Foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to use syscall statx() in app deployed in Cloud Foundry. Unfortunately it does not work due to

```
"EPERM: Operation not permitted".
```

but I can use stat() without any problems.

Is there any way to allow my app to work?

Hint: I believe, the problem could be the configuration of the seccomp profile in runtime garden-runC - it filters allowed syscalls and statx is not on the allowed list.

Comment: If Seccomp is restricting it, there's nothing you as an app dev can do to bypass that. I would suggest opening an issue on Github, I think https://github.com/cloudfoundry/guardian would be the right place.

Comment: @DanielMikusa is there any way to baypass it as cloud operator?

Comment: I don't think so, it looks like it needs a code fix. Unless you're willing to make a code change & recompile everything on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found workaround: if privileged container support is enabled, statx() can be used and works well

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cf-deployment/blob/main/operations/enable-privileged-container-support.yml

Unfortunately, this is really bad idea and it is decreases security. More details: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html